# Although certificates are pinned, NSURLErrorDomain error -1012

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

```
[manager setSecurityPolicy:[AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate]];
NSLog(@"Using %lu pinned certificates", (unsigned long)[requestManager.securityPolicy.pinnedCertificates count]);
```

I am using AFNetworking 2.0, and I have enabled certificate authentication on the server. I have placed two .crt files in the xcode project. and whenever I try to establish a https connection to the server I get the NSURLErrorDomain error -1012. Interesting thing to note here is that in my logs I can see the count of loaded certificates as 2. So, I guess pinning is successful, can someone help me with whats is wrong here?

Also, instead of pinning if I write - `[sec setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES]` then everything works fine.

Comment: What hostname are the certificates for? Have you added all of the chain certificates?

Comment: These certificates are issued by a CA